# Cassandra transactions / batch statements

Tags: datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

We are using Cassandra as a backing store in our product and want RDBMS transaction like behavior i.e. execute all or nothing.

We could achieve this behaviour with logged batch statement(Cassandra java driver) , but as our batch contains multiple objects with different partition keys, we are getting limited by batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb.

In many places it is suggested to keep batch size small - but in our case can't reduce batch size as it is dynamically prepared by product.

Please suggest.

We tried to increase batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb, but doesnt look like good option as mentioned in documentation as it could affect performance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.